# Populate UITableView from Structs With Specific Keyword

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct

I have a struct:

```
class Song: CustomStringConvertible {
    let title: String
    let artist: String

    init(title: String, artist: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(title) \(artist)"
    }
}

var songs = [
    Song(title: "Song Title 3", artist: "Song Author 3"),
    Song(title: "Song Title 2", artist: "Song Author 2"),
    Song(title: "Song Title 1", artist: "Song Author 1"),
    Song(title: "Song Title 0", artist: "Song Author 1")
]
```

that dispays on a `UITableView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : LibrarySongTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Library Cell") as! LibrarySongTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel = songs[indexPath.row].title
    cell.artistLabel = songs[indexPath.row].artist
}
```

I want to display all of the songs that are by the same artist in another `UITableViewController`. So say that I say the artist is **Song Author 1**. I want **Song Title 0** and **Song Title 1** to populate the UITableViewController. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

For your other `UITableViewController` create another song list like the following:

```
var author1Songs = songs.filter { song -> Bool in
    return song.artist == "Song Author 1"
}
```

Then you can use that to populate your other table just like you did using `songs`.

I'm assuming you are using a new UITableViewController, so you need to make sure you provide the correct number of sections and correct number of rows.

So when you return the number of rows, you need to use `author1Songs.count`.  Don't use the same row count as `songs`.

Comment: I get an error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` whenever I call `cell.titleLabel = author1Songs[indexPath.row].title`

Comment: I updated the answer, make sure you are returning `author1Songs.count` when the table ask for number of rows. Don't just reuse `songs.count`.  I am assuming you are creating a new UITableViewController?